# Screen Brightness reset issue

Tags: 20.04, screen, brightness, unlock

I have a brand new lenovo 5 pro laptop with Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot installation, and I am facing a weird issue. Every time my screen sleeps and locks due to inactivity, and when I unlock it again, the screen brightness resets to maximum. When I move the brightness slider, the brightness adjusts to the corresponding level of the slider. This only happens during screen sleep, lock and unlock cycle. Does not happen after suspend, restart or hibernate. All the solutions I found pertained to Ubuntu 12.04 or thereabout. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1363117/edit) the question to add this information.